# disassemble c++ dll roughly to machine code

Tags: c++, assembly, binary-data

I know that you cannot have a C++ dll and expect to have it as a source code, am I right? But at the same time, when I revert a C++ dll to raw data, using DUMPBIN, then there are some stuff which can be done to interpret it, right? For example, we know basic mappings for most popular operators and all.

Is there a tool that can roughly interpret that raw machine data to something that looks more to a code or instruction? The issue is that I do not have enough time to write it myself to scratch! so I am looking for a tool or something to do it.

Comment: Did you google for "decompiler"? I found [this one](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/), though it doesn't mention if it can decompile dlls.

Comment: Unless they miraculously matured while I wasn't looking, decompilers tend to produce relatively useless code that is more wordy than the disassembled code, with every operation "spelled out" and even some register names in the source. You'd be better off reading the disassembled code directly.

Comment: Ye i did but most decompilers are poor while working with DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **disassembler**, which is a tool that takes a binary object (like a compiled file, a library, or even an executable) and tries to reinterpret its content as assembly.

With a tool like that you can usually retrieve the names of the internal symbols (unless of course the binary image is stripped, but this is not the case for dynamically liked libraries).

Also for C++ this is a bit difficult because of name [mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Try to give a glance to [Objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump).

Answer (score 0):

YOu can disassemble the code sections of the DUMPBIN /DISASS - but if you want "code" like C++, then you need a decompiler. However, they are far from great, and often make quite unreadable code - yes, it's something that you can feed into a compiler, but it's hardly what I'd call "human readable".

Comment: "and often make quite unreadable code" is also acceptable in my case!

Answer (score 0):

In my biased opinion, the best disassembler out there is IDA (Interactive Disassembler). It is somewhat expensive since it's targeted towards professional use, but there's a freeware (older) version you can try:

http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml

The [Hex-Rays Decompiler](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) (an add-on for IDA) can produce C pseudocode from the disassembly, which can in many cases be recompiled again.

Comment: Well I tried Hex-Rays and this looks like a sound decompiler however it is not so good with DLLs.  Am I right? I get a little stupid code after decompiling it.

Comment: I can't see your screen from here so I don't know what you mean by "little stupid code". IDA and the decompiler certainly work just fine with DLLs, as with many other input file formats.